# Windows share - wrong password

Tags: network-share, password, windows

Disclaimer: I'm completely new to this.

I'm trying to connect to a windows share folder in a different network. When I start remote desktop to the machine with the shared folder, the shared folder works (within the remote desktop: `\\DOMAIN\\sharedfolder\` works as expected).

However, if I now try to connect from my own machine, neither the combination user / password, nor `DOMAIN\user` / password works, and all I get is "The specified network password is not correct".

Is there some magic trick to this? Do I have to type in `DOMAIN\password` or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, is the same DOMAIN\user account being used to log into the remote desktop session that you are trying to use locally?  You say "different network" so, that's why I ask.  Do you mean different domain entirely?  Or possibly they gave you a local server account to use?

Things to test:

1. From your machine can you ping the server that you are trying to reach?
2. If so, can you click start, run, then enter "\SERVERNAME" and hit enter and it then prompts for credentials?

If it does prompt, then you should be able to enter the same credentials you use to start the remote desktop session (paying special attention to the DOMAIN name if it is on a different domain or a local server account ID).

Bottom line:  if you can actually reach the remote server from your PC then whatever credentials you use to login to the remote desktop session should work to get you access to the remote share.

Comment: (How do I insert new lines here :( )
My computer is in the `MY-DESKTOP` domain, so it will choose the username `MY-DESKTOP\USER` if I don't specify the domain. \\     
1. `ping server.com` works, `ping DOMAIN` works \\     
2. run -> `\\DOMAIN` opens a promt, but there's instantly an error at the bottom: `Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password` (probably because my login name, domain and password differ from the  data for the server), and it resets me to the Domain `MY-DESKTOP` \\     
run -> `\\server.com` -> `DOMAIN\user`/`password/` works :D thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly does this shared folder reside? On the domain? If yes then the domain user account would need access associated with the appropriate ACL. Are you able to use network tools to test connectivity like tracert or ping? Because that would identify network issues and also assume access issues if not...

Answer (score -2):

Humm check your network setting 
update your group policies
flushdns 
use domain\user
it should work

Comment: This is a terrible answer.

Comment: done everything and still doesn't work :(

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. This answer does not meet our quality standards - It is a ["button-pushing" answer](http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/06/09/press-the-green-button-twice/) which does nothing to help someone understand the cause of the problem, or how to address the root cause so it won't reoccur. Please consider updating your answer to explain ***why*** you think this is a good solution, and *what underlying cause(s) it is designed to address*.  Thanks!